# Affine manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory

An affine manifold is a topological manifold which admits a system of charts such that the coordinate changes are (restrictions of) affine transformations. Let $M$ be a compact affine manifold. Let $G$ be the fundamental group of $M$ and $\tilde M$ be its universal cover. One can show that each $n$-dimensional affine manifold comes with a developing map $D\colon \tilde M \to \mathbb R^n$, and a homomorphism $\varphi \colon G \to {\rm Aff}(\mathbb R^n)$, such that $D$ is an immersion and equivariant with respect to $\varphi$.

An affine manifold is called *complete* if $D$ is a homeomorphism, in this case: $\varphi$ is injective, $G$ is a Bieberbach group, and $M$ is aspherical, i.e. $\tilde M$ is contractible. The non-complete case seems to be far more complicated.

> **Question 1:** Is there an easy example, where $D$ is not surjective?
>
> **Question 2:** Is there an easy example, where $\varphi$ is not injective?
>
> **Question 3:** Is there an easy example, where $M$ is not aspherical?

**EDIT:** As André suggested, let's ask for examples for which $\varphi$ takes values in $SL(n,\mathbb R) \ltimes \mathbb R^n$ or even $SL(n,\mathbb Z) \ltimes \mathbb R^n$, seen as subgroups of ${\rm Aff}(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: When a universal cover exists, the fundamental group acts faithfully on it, so there should be no examples for Question 2, unless I am confused by something.

Comment: You are right, $G$ acts faithfully on $\tilde M$; but not necessarily on $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a conjecture due to Markus which states that any compact affine manifold has parallel volume (*i.e.* the linear part of $\varphi$ lies in $\mathrm{SL}(n;\mathbb{R})$) if and only if it is complete. To the best of my knowledge, this conjecture is still open, which goes towards saying that there should be no easy examples to questions 1 and 3 for affine manifolds with parallel volume.

If the fundamental group $G$ of a compact affine manifold with parallel volume is nilpotent, the beautiful *Affine manifolds with nilpotent holonomy* by Fried, Goldman and Hirsch, Comm. Math. Helv. **56** (1981) proves that Markus' conjecture holds in this case and, thus, there are no examples to questions 1 and 3 with nilpotent fundamental group. The proof is a cunning mixture of representation theory and  geometry, so I strongly recommend taking a look at it. The results in this paper also imply that the above examples (to questions 1 and 3) constructed by Andre Henriques cannot be adapted so that the resulting manifolds admit parallel volume (these are, nonetheless, very nice examples to the original question!).

Answer (score 6):

An answer to questions **1** and **3** is prodvided by $(\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\})\big/\lambda^{\mathbb Z}$, where $\lambda^{\mathbb Z}$ acts by scalings.
That manifold is diffeomorphic to $S^{n-1}\times S^1$, and fails to be aspherical for $n\ge 3$.

The case $n = 2$ of the above construction can be used to produce an example of **2**. Take the double cover of $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$, and mod it out by $\lambda^{\mathbb Z}$. That manifold is diffeomorphic $S^1\times S^1$.

---

All this being said, my answers probably aren't very interesting.

I therefore suggest modifying the question, and asking for examples of ***integral affine manifolds***.
These are manifolds whose transition functions are taken from the group $SL(n,\mathbb Z)\ltimes \mathbb R^n$.
I would be very interested to see examples of those.

Comment: For 2 take an appropriate double cover of your example with n=2.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. We had the same idea at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I modified the question a bit to make place for different answers.

Comment: What is $\lambda^\mathbb{Z}$ in this context?

Comment: @goblin It's the set $ \{..., \lambda^{-2}, \lambda^{-1}, 1, \lambda, \lambda^2, \lambda^3, ... \}$, viewed as a group under multiplication.