# Smooth manifold with affine structure: aspherical?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, sg.symplectic-geometry

I wonder if a smooth manifolds $M$ which admits an affine structure must necessarily satisfy $\pi_2(M)=0$.

By affine structure I mean an atlas all of whose change of coordinates maps are affine maps. This kind of manifolds occur as bases of Lagrangian fibrations. If the answer to the above question is yes, this would imply that the fibers of a Lagrangian fibration are always incompressible (their $\pi_1$ injects in the total space).

Comment: see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70668/affine-manifolds

Comment: The base of a Lagrangian fibration inherits an integral affine structure, i.e. the linear parts of the changes of coordinates are invertible over the integers. While it is not hard to construct non-compact examples of manifolds admitting an integral affine structure with non-trivial second homotopy group, to the best of my knowledge, it is not known whether there is a compact example. This is, in fact, related to the question that Francesco Polizzi linked in his comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No they are not, you can consider $\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$ or the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$ by the map $h_c(x)=cx, c>1$ which is $S^2\times S^1$.